# Cannot construct from lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

I'm stuck with a compilation problem. I do not understand why the following code does not compile:

```
#include <functional>

namespace async {

template<class ...T>
using Callback = std::function<void(const std::string& result, T ...args)>;

template<class Signature>
class Function;

template<class Res, class ...Args>
class Function<Res(Args...)>
{
    std::function<void(Args ...args, const Callback<Res>&)> m_function;
public:
    Function(std::function<void(Args ...args, const Callback<Res>&)>&& function) : m_function(std::move(function)) {}
    Function& operator=(std::function<void(Args ...args, const Callback<Res>&)>&& function) {m_function = std::move(function); return *this;}
    void operator()(Args... args, const Callback<Res>& callback) const {m_function(args..., callback);}
};

}

async::Function<int(int)> getF()
{
    return [](int i, const async::Callback<int> callback)
    {
        callback("", i);
    };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto f0 = getF();
    return 0;
}
```

gcc says:

> In function ‘async::Function getF()’:
>   error: could not convert ‘getF()::__lambda0{}’ from ‘getF()::__lambda0’ to ‘async::Function’

icc says:

> error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "lambda [](int, async::Callback)->void" to "async::Function" exists

Now if I replace

```
    return [](int i, const async::Callback<int> callback)
    {
        callback("", i);
    };
```

by

```
    return async::Function<int(int)>([](int i, const async::Callback<int> callback)
    {
        callback("", i);
    });
```

Then it works.
Why to I need to cast explicitely and how to avoid this?

---

A simpler solution would be to replace the class Function by something like

```
template<class Signature>
using Function = std::nullptr_t;

template<class Res, class ...Args>
using Function<Res(Args...)> = std::function<void(Args ...args, const Callback<Res>&)>;
```

But the specialization with `<Res(Args...)>` does not compile...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no `Function` constructor that accepts a lambda. There is one that accepts an `std::function`, and there's also an `std::function` constructor that accepts a lambda, but C++ will never combine two implicit user-defined conversions for you.

The easiest way to define the needed constructor is

```
template <class T>
Function (T&& t) : m_function(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
```

Comment: @SimonKraemer one could also remove `async::Function` altogether and use naked `std::function` instead...